# HTML5 video not playing on Ipad/Android

Tags: html, video

I have an MP4 video that I am trying to play via HTML5 on Android and iPad.

The html code is

```
<video width="510" height="315" autobuffer controls >
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The media information on the video from VLC is

```
Stream 0:
    Type: Video
    Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
    Resolution: 856x368
    Frame rate: 23.976000
    Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
Stream 1
    Type: Audio
    Code: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
    Channels: Stereo
    Sample rate: 44100 Hz
```

I created the video by converting another using ffmpeg using vcodec libx264 acodec aac

The iPad just shows a play icon with a line through on a black screen

Is this likely to happen because the video is in the wrong format?

Answer (score 0):

Today my friend has similar problem; 
I tried Edge 42 on Windows 10, or FireFox,Google chrome on android, it doesn't play the video. So I use VLC to convert this meida to remove encoding format 'Planar'. Then I can play it on the above browsers.

Software I used: VLC Media Player Version 3.0.3 Vetinari

The media information on the video from VLC is

`Stream 0
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Type: Video
Video resolution: 759x720
Buffer dimensions: 768x738
Frame rate: 30
Decoded format: Planar 4:4:4 YUV
Orientation: Top left
Chroma location: Left`

After converted, it works, 
Here is my parameter:
Convert 
Settings
Profile [Video for Youtube HD] and edit selected profile, 
disable Audio codec(because I don't need audio, try it if you need this part), 
check Video codec -> Resolusion and choose frame size you want.
Finally Convert & Save it.

The media information on the video from VLC is

`Stream 0
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Language: English
Type: Video
Video resolution: 758x720
Buffer dimensions: 768x720
Frame rate: 30.689656
Decoded format: 
Orientation: Top left
Chroma location: Left`

Answer (score -1):

You can find an excellent tutorial here that can help you :

http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/tutorial-serving-html5-video-cross-browser-including-ipad/

I think your problem is the encoding. Ipad video plays well with mov format.

Comment: I have tried encoding the video as a mov and it makes no difference